# Reliable verification of codesigned app in OSX

Tags: macos, codesign

After many problems to codesign an Mac OSX app finally I got a working combination (what to sign, where it should be located).

My question is if there's some system command to do the *exact* same verification the system does on a downloaded app. I've used codesign --display and RB App Checker that passed the verification in some cases but when downloading the app didn't succeed.

Comment: How are you packaging your app?  Zip?  An installer?  Some forms of packaging will corrupt the code signing.  This may be why you see it failing after downloading.

Comment: Sorry for the vague question, it was a long day. I am packing on a dmg, I've made sure there are no changes in the packed app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of Mac OS X you develop under, or what version of Mac OS X you're downloading and testing on.  That's important because there were changes in code signatures and GateKeeper in Mavericks and later.

See [Apple's tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html) for details, but what I use is:

```
spctl -a -v path/to/my.app
```

Comment: Thank you! that's what I was looking for and in case of failure it gives a concies reason.